# ASP.NET Core custom token provider use across different projects

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

I've implemented a custom token provider by inheriting from `DataProtectorTokenProvider` and then registering it.

I can generate tokens, but they only validate inside the same project.

I need to generate the token when `UserManager` is running inside one website and then validate the token using the same `UserManager` code but running in a different webite.

Both websites do

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName("Whatever");
```

I thought that setting the application name would get around this, but apparently not.

When the second website tries to validate the token it fails saying

> The provided payload cannot be decrypted because it was not protected with this protection provider. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning

Any ideas how to make it work?

Or do I need a workaround such as storing the token in the `UserTokens` table?

With

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {

      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "Trace"
    },
```

on creating the token I see

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector: Trace: Performing protect operation to key {7f8d00fb-e304-4476-9f01-1277b8936886} with purposes ('Whatever', 'RegistrationTokenProvider').
```

and when trying to validate I see:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector: Trace: Performing unprotect operation to key {7f8d00fb-e304-4476-9f01-1277b8936886} with purposes ('Whatever', 'RegistrationTokenProvider').
```

The GUIDs are the same and the `Whatever` seems to be a red herring since my `RegistrationTokenProvider` is there in both cases.
So what is the matter with this?

Comment: for sharing authentication tokens or any protected payloads between multiple applications or instances, you ahve to make sure that the data protection keys are consistent across these applications. you can achieve this  by using  configuring the same key storage location and also check applications can access and use each other's keys.
here is the sample code:`builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("Whatever")
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\shared-location\keys"));`

Answer (score 0):

if you want To share tokens between applications, ensure they access the same data protection keys
by configuring a shared storage (example -> a common file system path) for keys using `'.PersistKeysToFileSystem()'`.
Both applications must also use '`.SetApplicationName("Whatever")'` to align the data protection context.
If issues persist, you can consider centralized authentication solutions like OAuth2/OpenID Connect or a shared database for token validation,
though these approaches have their complexities. Key configuration discrepancies, s
uch as cryptographic algorithms, should be checked to ensure they match across applications.